# How to find out whether a list contains any letters

Tags: python, list, letter

I have a list that I am trying to get a false return on if it contains any letters. When I get to the list that is as follows:

```
list = ['1', '+', 'b1']
```

I try to run

```
any(characters.isalpha() for characters in list)
```

but it is returning False, even though list[2] clearly contains a letter.

So I tried to do the following, thinking that I might not have properly iterated over each item in list:

```
for characters in list:
  any(characters.isalpha() for char in characters)
```

which returns

```
False
False
False
```

I'm at a loss for how to get the program to pick up that there is a letter and return True for a query about whether list contains any letters. If you could help me figure the answer to that I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `'+'.isalpha()` is actually False, cause it's not alpha, like [a-zA-Z]

Comment: also I know its probably not your real variable name... but you should never ever ever name your variable things like `list` or `int` or `float`, not even in (maybe especially) example snippets ... instead at the very least name it `my_list`, or `my_int` or something... dont shadow builtins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another `for ... in ...` clause to iterate over each character in each string:

```
>>> lst = ['1', '+', 'b1']
>>> any(char.isalpha() for string in lst for char in string)
True
>>>
```

`for char in string` takes each string returned by `for string in lst` and iterates over its characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
for characters in letter:
  any(characters.isalpha() for char in characters)
```

You have a typo there, you probably mean:

```
for characters in letter:
  any(char.isalpha() for char in characters)
```

What’s more, you can merge these two loops into one, inside a generator expression:

```
any(char.isalpha() for letters in list for char in letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with either `any` or `all`

```
>>> all(character.isalpha() for item in alist for character in item)
False
>>> any(character.isalpha() for item in alist for character in item)
True
>>> ## if you want the same output as using any
>>> not all(character.isalpha() for item in alist for character in item)
True
```

Incidentally, `all` is faster (at least in this relatively small case)

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('not all(character.isalpha() for item in ["1", "+", "b1"] for character in item)', number=10000)
0.021654181380604598
>>> timeit.timeit('any(character.isalpha() for item in ["1", "+", "b1"] for character in item)', number=10000)
0.034381219301721444
```

This doesn't hold true if you change the order though

```
>>> timeit.timeit('not all(character.isalpha() for item in ["b1", "+", "1"] for character in item)', number=10000)
0.0663501940999538
>>> timeit.timeit('any(character.isalpha() for item in ["b1", "+", "1"] for character in item)', number=10000)
0.037434049209622344
```

so picking one or the other is largely personal preference